# Prove that $ \mathcal{ L } $ (E, F) is a vectorial subspace of $ \mathcal{ F } $ (E, F)

Tags: linear-algebra

Given vectorial subspaces E y F, How can I prove that  $ \mathcal{ L } $ (E, F)  (which is the vectorial space of all the linear transformations from E to F) is a vectorial subspace of $ \mathcal{ F } $ (E, F)  (which is the real vectorial subspace of the real functions of a real variable
$ \mathit{ f :  R \to  R } $ )

I tried to use the next knowledge:
To prove that it's a subspace I have to prove three things:
First, that 0 $\in$ F , second that If  u, v $\in$ F, then u + v $\in$ F and finally, If v $\in$ F, then $\alpha$  v $\in$ F, $\; \forall  \alpha \in \mathit {R} $

But, I couldn't figure out How I can do it.

Comment: I'm a little foggy on your write up:  what is meant by the description of $\mathcal F$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zero function is the zero linear transformation, so it's in there.

If we have two linear transformations from $E$ to $F$, we can add them and we certainly get a linear transformation from $E$ to $F$.  So that's the second condition.

I leave the third condition to you.